# Raspberry Pi as high current PoE source

Tags: poe

I'm trying to set up my Raspberry Pi 4 as a POE power source that the rest of its project will use. We currently use a separate POE injector and supporting parts, which is really messy. Most of the content I read about this don't use the Pi as their power source; nearly all HATs I read about are splitters and not injectors. I have power available as 20V and 24V and I need ~100W of power. I also need a gigabit ethernet port (a few components require it despite that the actual amount of data is much lower).

Has anyone had any luck injecting this amount of power at their Pi via a Hat or something similar? Is it possible? Or would it be easier to do via a compute module instead since the ethernet pins are more readily accessible?

Comment: never use the Raspberry Pi as a power supply for anything that requires more than a few hundred milliamps ... drawing too much current may turn the RPi into an expensive fuse

Comment: Why not use a SEPIC converter.